# Rewrite Checkout Success

Tags: magento2, checkout

i want to rewrite checkout `success.phtml` file in my moudule currently success.phtml file coming from my theme folder like

> app/design/frontend/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

now i want this file in my module i done this but not wroking for me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="checkout.success">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mymodule_Module::success.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Comment: Answered try this and let us know

Answer (score 1):

Create the file

> app/code/Mymodule/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.success" template="Mymodule_Module::checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: not working i treid but still file coming same folder

Comment: hmmm then i make change in theme file

Comment: you can Magento_Checkout  layout file removed it and Please don't forget to clear cache after change in layout xml files

Answer (score 1):

If you need override success page in theme,
Create layout file:

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml
```

With code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.success" template="Magento_Checkout::checkout/custom-success.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

And create template in your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/checkout/custom-success.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

create template in your theme:

app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/templates/custom-success.phtml